# Song during Heart of the Swarm Ending Cinematic

Tags: starcraft-2, game-music-identification

What is the name of the song used during the heart of the swarm ending cinematic? You can hear it at the following link:

Right now listening to the whole heart of the swarm soundtrack and I still can't figure it out. "Fire in the sky" and "whispering from the stars" are pretty close though.

List of Heart of the swarm songs:
Songs name:

- Corruptors: 00:00:00
- Heart of the Swarm: 00:07:52
- Collateral damage : 00:15:17
- Fire in the sky: 00:20:43
- Stronger: 00:28:50
- The coming storm: 00:35:16
- Conscience: 00:42:32
- Phantoms of the void: 00:50:19
- He had it coming: 00:57:47
- Ascension: 01:04:30
- Whispering from the Stars: 01:10:36

Not knowing the song is driving me crazy.

Comment: A lot of songs from the game aren't on the soundtrack *([example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVgjGyPIh1c))*.  Most of them can be extracted from the game's .mpq files, but I have a feeling that this one is baked directly into the cinematic, and was recorded specifically for this scene.  Unless it's used elsewhere in the game, it probably has no name, and you're probably out of luck finding it without the voice-overs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called **Ascension** by composer Neal Acree, featuring *The Skywalker Symphony and Chorus*, and vocalist Laurie Ann Haus.

Neal Acree has released the full track on his Youtube page:

I stumbled upon this a few days ago. I hope you're still around to enjoy it!

Answer (score 4):

It is **Ascension by Neal Acree** ([SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/neal-acree/starcraft-ii-heart-of-the-7)).