# Gmod - Music on map jb_summer

Tags: garrys-mod

I was wondering - what are all the songs called in the disco area of the jail-break map named "jb_summer".

Comment: Typically we ask for a link to audio/video artifacts for "identify this..." questions, though this one is in the gray area since you're asking about a song in a well-known game.  Even with a video/audio link, it would still be a gray-area question since you're asking about music-identification rather than game-identification, but I think it would be acceptable given that [this similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117568) was also deemed acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been awhile since I've played jailbreak, so this might be wrong, but two songs are The Pursuit of Happiness by Kid Cudi and Chasing the Sun - Tantrum Desire Remix by The Wanted. Really good songs.