# Lyrics from Afterlife soundtrack

Tags: afterlife

In the old game, Afterlife (Lucas Arts), there is a song that features a chant. The song is the most peaceful of the soundtrack, in my opinion, and I have always wondered what the chant was. The song can be found here:

.

It seems that the song is Buddhist or Hindi inspired. It is similar to the chant played when founding Buddhism in Civilization IV. A video of that chant can be found here:

.

If anyone can help me figure out what the mantra/chant of the song is, I would be eternally grateful. I cannot find an answer via Google.

Comment: This question is borderline, but given the existence of [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117568) I believe it should be on-topic.

Comment: @Schism Thanks for adding the 'afterlife' tag. I was unable to add the tag due to low reputation.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/what-are-the-lyrics-to-the-turret-opera-at-the-end-of-portal-2)